"failed to fetch user profile" Error While Authenticating LinkedIn in Passport JS OAuth2
I'm having following error while authenticating LinkedIn in Passport JS.
{
"message": "LinkedIn authentication failed",
"error": "failed to fetch user profile"
}

Here is my code:
passport.use(
  new LinkedInStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: 'https://analyser-node.octalooptechnologies.com/auth/linkedin/callback',
      scope: ['email', 'profile'],
    },
    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      // console.log('Access Token:', accessToken);
      console.log('Profile:', profile);
      console.log('hi');
      
      try {
        let user = await User.findOne({ linkedinId: profile.id });

        if (user) {
          return done(null, user);
        }

        user = await User.findOne({ email: profile.emails[0].value });
        if (user) {
          if (!user.linkedinId) {
            user.linkedinId = profile.id;
            user.verify = true;
            await user.save();
          }
          console.log('user in strategy:', user);
          
          return done(null, user);
        }

        const newUser = new User({
          linkedinId: profile.id,
          email: profile.emails[0].value,
          verify: true,
        });
        await newUser.save();
        done(null, newUser);
      } catch (error) {
        done(error, null);
      }
    }
  )
);

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(id);
    done(null, user);
  } catch (error) {
    done(error, null);
  }
});

exports.linkedinAuth = passport.authenticate('linkedin', { state: true, scope: ['email', 'profile']});

exports.linkedinAuthCallback = (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('linkedin', { session: false }, async (error, user, info) => {
    console.log('info:', info);
    
    console.log('user in callback:', user);
    
    if (error) {
      console.error('LinkedIn authentication error:', error);
      return res.status(400).json({ message: 'LinkedIn authentication failed error', error: error.message });
    }

    if (!user) {
      const message = info ? info.message : 'User already registered with LinkedIn';
      return res.redirect(`https://analyser-node.octalooptechnologies.com/login?error=${encodeURIComponent(message)}`);
    }

    try {
      const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user._id }, secretKey, { expiresIn: '1h' });
      const redirectUrl = `https://cv-analyzer-git-staging-octalooptechnologies-projects.vercel.app/recommendation?token=${token}&userId=${user._id}`;
      res.redirect(redirectUrl);
    } catch (jwtError) {
      console.error('JWT generation error:', jwtError);
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error during JWT generation' });
    }
  })(req, res, next);
};

Also, I'm curious to know why the console 'hi' isn't printing? I'm actually confused about the flow of the process. Would be appreciated if someone guide about that.
Note: Please read the question thoroughly instead of downvoting or suggesting a dupicate as there are the details that differ from other questions posted earlier.
Here is the link to a short video demonstrating this issue: https://www.loom.com/share/91594aa0c7b2408cb262e1ea407d5558
